# How to parse json objects that have different keys in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swift3

Hey I was wondering if its possible to parse json objects that have different keys. I've been searching but haven't found a solution. Everything I came across have the same keys but a value of nil or null. Here is the json file I'm trying to parse, it's an array of objects but some objects have different keys.

```
{
data: [
  {
    "first_name": "John",
    "middle_name": "Bob",
    "last_name": "Dom"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Juan",
    "last_name": "Garcia"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "German",
    "middle_name": "Steve",
    "last_name": "Ramirez"
  } 
 ]
}
```

I'm using CoreData. I have created two entities, one called Person and another one called PersonWithMiddleName. Person has two attributes firstName and lastName. The PersonWithMiddleName has middle name and the Person is the parent entity. This has my data model looks like.

[image]

This is the code I use to parse the json file.

[image]

At the person initialization, I get stuck. Im trying to initialize a Person if it only has a first name and a last name keys. Then I'm trying to initialize a PersonWithMiddleName if they have first, middle and last names keys.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to check a json object that has a certain key that others objects in the array don't have and cast it to a certain class. Or does every object in the array have to have the same key and a value of nil/null if no middle name.

Would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if we can search for the key, but with basic if-else condition you may achieve this.

```
if let firstName = personData["FirstName"] {

        if let lastName = personData["LastName"] {

            if let middleName = personData["middleName"] {
                let person = PersonWithMiddleName(context: context)
                person.firstName =
                    person.lastName =
                    person.middleName =
            } else {
                let person = Person(context: context)
                person.firstName =
                    person.lastName =
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Hey Bhupesh, I'm Wondering if there is another way to initialize person. I'm taking this course online that the instructor does something a little different. He uses some code that looks like this: let person = some condition ? PersonWithMiddleName(context: context) : Person(context: context)]. Im trying to initialize person like this. In the condition, where if the object has a middle name key it initialize person to PersonWithMiddleName else a Person. Or is the answer you provided the same thing.

Comment: Both are same. If you are sure that firstName and lastName will never be nil, then you can simply use the below statement. person will be initialised with PersonWithMiddleName if middleName is not nil, otherwise person will be initialised with Person.  let person = middleName.isEmpty ? Person(context: context) : PersonWithMiddleName(context: context)

Comment: Thank you, Bhupesh

Answer (score 0):

This essentially the same as the other answer, but I just expand from your existing code. See the comment on the code for what is changed

```
for personData in jsonArray {

    //FirstName
    guard let firstName = personData["first_name"] as? String else {
        return
    }

    //LastName
    guard let firstName = personData["last_name"] as? String else {
        return
    }

    //Fork here to check if there are middle name or not, yes you still can test it as? String even if it nil
    if let middleName = personData["middle_name"] as? String {
        let person = PersonWithMiddleName(context: context)
        person.firstName = firstName
        person.middleName = middleName
        person.lastName = lastName
    } else {
        // Your orignal code on person
        let person = PersonWithMiddleName(context: context)
        person.firstName = firstName
        person.middleName = middleName
        person.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

It actually the same thing, but if you want the style to be like your online lecturer then maybe you want like

```
for personData in jsonArray {

    //FirstName
    guard let firstName = personData["first_name"] as? String else {
        return
    }

    //LastName
    guard let firstName = personData["last_name"] as? String else {
        return
    }

    let middleName = personData["middle_name"] as? String

    //Base on your comment, this is what you need?
    let person = middleName == nil ? Person(context: context) : PersonWithMiddleName(context: context)
    person.firstName = firstName
    person.lastName = lastName

    // some more check here
    if person is PersonWithMiddleName
    {
        person.middleName = middleName
    }
}
```

Below code, is another form of forking where if **middleName == nil**, it will choose **Person(context: context)** else it will choose **PersonWithMiddleName(context: context)** as **person** variable

```
let person = middleName == nil ? Person(context: context) : PersonWithMiddleName(context: context)
```

Comment: Sidhi this work great. I'm Wondering if there is another way to initialize person, cause I am taking this course online that the instructor does something a little different. He uses some code that looks like this: let person = some condition ? PersonWithMiddleName(context: context) : Person(context: context)]. Im trying to initialize person like this. In the condition, where if the object has a middle name key it initialize person to PersonWithMiddleName else a Person. Or is the answer you provided the same thing.

Comment: Hi @LuisRamirez, It essentially the same, please check my edit for more information

Comment: Thank you, Sidhi for the help  :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use SwiftyJSON to do it , easy and simple